# Finding a closed-form formula to a recurrence with summation of past terms

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, recursion

I'm trying to find a closed form formula for the following recurrence problem but I'm having some difficulty:
\begin{align}
g(n) &= -\frac{1}{n+1} - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+1}g(i) \\
&= \frac{1}{n+1} \biggl( -1 - n\sum_{i=1}^{n} g(i) \biggr)
\end{align}

With $$g(0) = -\frac{1}{3}$$

I've seen several other posts use generator functions which I've attempted to use but got stuck relatively quickly.
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g(n)\,x^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \biggl( \frac{1}{n+1} 
\Bigl( -1 - (n) \sum_{i=1}^{n}g(i) \Bigr)x^n \biggr) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \biggl( \frac{x^n}{n+1} 
\Bigl( -1 - (n) \sum_{i=1}^{n}g(i) \Bigr) \biggr) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} - \frac{x^n}{n+1} 
- \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\biggl( \frac{x^n(n)}{n+1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} g(i) \biggr) \\
&= \frac{\log(1-x)}{x} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \biggl( \frac{x^n(n)}{n+1} 
\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(i) \biggr) 
\end{align}

But I'm not too sure where to go from there.

Comment: Why do you have an $(n+1)$ in front of the sum of $g(i)$s in the second line expressing $g(n)$?

Comment: To clarify: are you trying to determine the sequence $\{g(1), g(2), \dots \}$? Or does the indexing begin at $n=0$?

Comment: Concern: In order to solve a recurrence, you have to have initial value(s). What is $g(0)$ or $g(1)$ or wherever this sequence begins?

Comment: Another concern: Did you mean to express $g(n)$ in terms of itself (as the last term in the sum on the right)?

Comment: @gary that was a mistake it should be $ (n-1) $ edited the original post to reflect that. I also added $ g(1) $ which starts the indexing.

Comment: @sammy yup its recursive like that

Comment: The two lines for $g(n)$ are not equal. $(n-1)$ should not be there at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to be careful with the writing of the problem as mentioned in the comments. You also mention the value of $g(0)$ to be $-\frac{1}{3}$ but I think you mean $g(1)$. Therefore, I will solve the problem so it is consistent with $g(1)=-\frac{1}{3}$ and using the definition
$$
g(n)=-\frac{1}{n+1}\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^ng(i)\right)
$$
which is the same as the first line you have written.

Let $s(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n g(i)$. Then, we have
$$
g(n)=-\frac{1}{n+1}(1+s(n))
$$
On the other hand, note that $g(n)=s(n)-s(n-1)$, and hence we can plug this into the above to get
$$
s(n)-s(n-1)=-\frac{1}{n+1}(1+s(n))
$$
or after simplifying a bit
$$
(n+2)s(n)-(n+1)s(n-1)=-1.
$$
One can guess that $s(n)=-\frac{n}{n+2}$ solves such equation and satisfies $s(1)=g(1)=-\frac{1}{3}$.
Hence, we have
$$
\begin{align}
g(n)&=s(n)-s(n-1)\\
&=-\frac{n}{n+2}+\frac{n-1}{n+1}\\
&=-\frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}.
\end{align}
$$